# Expected argument of type "string", "stdClass" given Error

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, mailchimp-api-v3.0, stdclass

I'm using mailchimp-api-v3 for nodejs. I'm currently trying to update a user's tag but sometimes this error pops up and I have no idea what it means. I searched around but it doesn't seem like a lot of devs have encountered it.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

```
try {
await mailchimp.post('/lists/' + listIDUsers + '/members/' + crypto.createHash('md5').update(profileSnap.val().email.toLowerCase()).digest("hex") + '/tags', {
        tags: [{name: "traveler", status: "active"}]
    });
} catch (error) {
if (error.status === 404) {
await mailchimp.post('/lists/' + listIDUsers + '/members', {
            email_address: profileSnap.val().email,
            status: 'subscribed',
            merge_fields: {
                "FNAME": profileSnap.val().firstName,
                "LNAME": profileSnap.val().lastName,
                "UID": uid,
                "EMAIL": profileSnap.val().email
            },
            tags: [{name: "traveler", status: "active"}]
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Issue for: " + uid);
        console.log(error);
 }
```

The error:

```
Error: Expected argument of type "string", "stdClass" given
    at Request._callback (/srv/node_modules/mailchimp-api-v3/index.js:506:30)
    at Request.self.callback (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Comment: What line of your code is it referring to?

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm not sure which line of code it's referring to, it would've helped me get closer to the solution if I knew :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've decided to go ahead and reach out to Mailchimp since this question has been left unanswered for a few days! They got back to me stating that the reason I'm getting the error above is that because I'm trying to set a tag for a subscriber right after adding the subscriber so the system wasn’t able to successfully add the tag because the subscriber hashed id wasn’t quiet created yet.

So all I needed was the following line of code to have my function wait 10 seconds before setting the tag.

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
await mailchimp.post('/lists/' + listIDUsers + '/members/' + crypto.createHash('md5').update(profileSnap.val().email.toLowerCase()).digest("hex") + '/tags', {
    tags: [{name: "traveler", status: "active"}]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the same problem I'm hitting. This looks like a mailchimp bug to me considering they allow tags in upserts... ‍♀️